# Changing rowspans

Tags: java, itext

I have been trying several hours handle (at the first sight) very simple issue in iText, have a look at this picture which describes my problem:

[image]
Could please someone change my code in the way it startes emitting the output what i want?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class App {
public static final String DEST = "c:/radek-folder/pdf1iTextZKOUSKA.pdf";
protected int horizontalAlignmentCenter = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
protected int verticalAlignmentMiddle = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
protected String fontTypeRegular = "c:/radek-folder/font_sitebook.ttf";
protected float fontSizeRegular = 10f;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new App().createPdf(DEST);
    System.out.println("done");
}

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    float[] columns = { 100, 50, 100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 75, 50, 50, 50 };
    int numberOfColumns = columns.length;
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 36, 36, 36, 36);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();

    PdfPTable subTableZkouska = new PdfPTable(numberOfColumns);
    subTableZkouska.setTotalWidth(columns);
    subTableZkouska.setLockedWidth(true);

    addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
            verticalAlignmentMiddle, "Brno Špitálka 8 Brno Hájecká 1068/14 CZ5159", 1,
            2, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);

    addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
            verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 2, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);

    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
                verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular,
                fontSizeRegular);
    }
    addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
            verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);

    document.add(subTableZkouska);
    document.close();
}

private static void addCellToTableCzech(PdfPTable table, int horizontalAlignment,
        int verticalAlignment, String value, int colspan, int rowspan,
        String fontType, float fontSize) {
    BaseFont base = null;
    try {
        base = BaseFont.createFont(fontType, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Font font = new Font(base, fontSize);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(value, font));
    cell.setColspan(colspan);
    cell.setRowspan(rowspan);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(horizontalAlignment);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(verticalAlignment);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    table.addCell(cell);
}
}
```

Comment: This looks like an identical question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002444/itext-how-to-change-rowspan-correctly

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - I do not interpret this question as blaming someone else. Most people, perhaps including you, have spent inordinate amounts of time on things that turn out to be quite trivial. Just accept the question and provide a helpful answer if you are able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understood properly the way how iText table is creating. This caused that i was unable to compute it correctly:

[image]
When i had realized what is in that picture, i already managed it smootly. It was only my fault, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a table with 12 columns, then you are adding cells like this:

```
// column 1, rows 1 and 3
addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
        verticalAlignmentMiddle, "Brno Špitálka 8 Brno Hájecká 1068/14 CZ5159", 1,
        2, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);
 // column 2, rows 1 and 2
 addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
        verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 2, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);
// columns 3 to 12, rows 1 and 2
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
            verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular,
            fontSizeRegular);
}
// column 1, row 3
addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
        verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);
```

As documented, iText's `PdfPTable` only renders complete rows, hence the last line will be ignored. This is consistent with the screen shot you shared about the resulting PDF created with iText. Why do you claim that there's a bug in iText?

Looking at the desired output, I would think you'd have this code:

```
// column 1, rows 1 and 2
addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
        verticalAlignmentMiddle, "Brno Špitálka 8 Brno Hájecká 1068/14 CZ5159", 1,
        2, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);
// columns 2 to 11, rows 1 and 2
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
            verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular,
            fontSizeRegular);
}
// column 12, rows 1 and 2
addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
        verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 2, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);
```

Conclusion: I don't think it's a bug in iText, but a bug in your code. I don't have the time, nor the inclination to test your code. I answered from my phone based on what I see. If you want someone to take a closer look, there's always paid support.

Comment: iText is open source. If you think there's a bug, feel free to fix it.

Comment: So i guess i was true that you did not even try to compile your solution, and now i am the bad one because i told you that it does not work and that i had already tried it before i posted this question.  Ok, then, my boss is gonna be happy.

Comment: I can't compile code on a phone. I read your code, saw an obvious logical error, and explained the error. If you want me to compile and test the code, I need to make time for that, and my time is not free. You can make your boss happy by explaining that getting a license for his use of iText also entitles you to support. If you make a support ticket explaining your issue, you will get an answer (and avoid the frustration that is caused when you want to get something for free).

Comment: Also: it is kind of strange that you choose to use iText 5 instead of iText 7. iText 5 is in maintenance mode, meaning it will be end of life by the end of 2018, and support for iText 5 is going to be discontinued in 2019.

Comment: I did the Math, based on your example. I counted the cells you were adding, taking into account the colspan and rowspan of every cell. That Math was wrong. Moreover, why would I do an effort for people who call me "Dude"?

Answer (score 0):

Bruno in his answer correctly analyzed the problem: It makes no sense here to add the second cell with rowspan 2 right after the first one because then it obviously is drawn in the second column, not in the twelfth column as desired by the OP.

His solution which he created offline, though, is incorrect.

If one wants the second cell with rowspan 2 to appear in the twelfth column, one has to add it as the twelfth cell! (Assuming that all cells involved have columnspan 1, that is... as in the case at hand.)

Thus:

```
public void createPdfFixed(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    float[] columns = { 100, 50, 100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 75, 50, 50, 50 };
    int numberOfColumns = columns.length;
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 36, 36, 36, 36);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();

    PdfPTable subTableZkouska = new PdfPTable(numberOfColumns);
    subTableZkouska.setTotalWidth(columns);
    subTableZkouska.setLockedWidth(true);

    // cell 1 with rowspan 2 >> column 1
    addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
            verticalAlignmentMiddle, "Brno Špitálka 8 Brno Hájecká 1068/14 CZ5159", 1,
            2, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);

    // cells 2-11 with rowspan 1 >> column 2-11 upper row
    for (int i = 2; i < 12; i++) {
        addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
                verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular,
                fontSizeRegular);
    }

    // cell 12 with rowspan 2 >> column 12
    addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
            verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 2, fontTypeRegular, fontSizeRegular);

    // cells 13-22 with rowspan 1 >> column 2-11 lower row
    for (int i = 13; i < 23; i++) {
        addCellToTableCzech(subTableZkouska, horizontalAlignmentCenter,
                verticalAlignmentMiddle, "38", 1, 1, fontTypeRegular,
                fontSizeRegular);
    }

    document.add(subTableZkouska);
    document.close();
}
```

([UseRowspan](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/UseRowspan.java#L129) method `createPdfFixed` used by test `testUseRowspanLikeUser7968180Fixed`)

Comment: thanks, but i have already fixed it, so i will not check it any more :-) But thanks for your effort.